# Displaying and Visualizing Difference between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I have two dataframes for different periods of time - `df_period_a` with

```
Vendor      Market
VendorA     MarketA
VendorA     MarketB
VendorX     MarketB
VendorZ     MarketB
VendorC     MarketX
VendorB     MarketX
VendorB     MarketA
VendorD     MarketA
```

and `df_period_b` as -

```
Vendor      Market
VendorA     MarketB
VendorX     MarketB
VendorZ     MarketB
VendorC     MarketB
VendorB     MarketX
VendorD     MarketX
VendorE     MarketB
VendorF     MarketC
```

which means `MarketA` has closed down and a new market `MarketC` has come up, along with a couple of new vendors `E` and `F`. I want to show this and the movement (if any) of vendors among markets with a `df_diff` like -

```
Source        Destination    Value
MarketX1        MarketX2        1
MarketA1        MarketX2        1
MarketB1        MarketX2        0
MarketX1        MarketB2        1
MarketB1        MarketB2        3
  -             MarketC2        1
  -             MarketB2        1
```

The `Value` here equals the number of vendors who have moved from `source` market in period `a` to `destination` market in period `b`.

Something that I tried doesn't work very accurately -

```py
def get_vendor_displacement_count(market_list, df_before, df_after):
    for market in market_list:
        df_moved_vendors = pd.merge(df_before, df_after, on=['Vendor'], how='inner')
        df_moved_vendors.rename(columns={'Market_x':'Source', 'Market_y':'Target'}, inplace=True)
        df_moved_vendors['Source'] = dict_periods[len(market_list)+1]  + " " +  df_moved_vendors['Source'].astype(str)
        df_moved_vendors['Target'] = dict_periods[len(market_list)] + " " + df_moved_vendors['Target'].astype(str)
    return df_moved_vendors
```

Also, would a Sankey diagram `(ipysankeywidget)` be the most appropriate diagram to show this displacement, or can I also look at some other visualizations for this? Thanks!

Comment: what are those values in the 'Value' column indicating? I guess source and destination are for vendors in  period_a and period_b respectively?  And what is 'MarketX1' as opposed to 'MarketX2'?

Comment: Try writing some code for this, even if it seems bad or slow or whatever.  Post that code so we can help you with it.  The question "can I also look at some other visualizations" is off topic on this site, as it is opinion-based and a poll and a request for recommendations.

Comment: Thanks @JohnZwinck and jeremy_rutman .. I've made some edits accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
dfa1 = df_period_a.assign(Value=1).set_index(['Vendor','Market'])
dfb1 = df_period_b.assign(Value=1).set_index(['Vendor','Market'])
diff = dfa1.join(dfb1, how='outer', lsuffix='a', rsuffix='b').fillna(0).astype(int)
res = (diff.Valueb - diff.Valuea).rename('Change').reset_index().query('Change != 0')
```

Result:

```
    Vendor   Market  Change
0  VendorA  MarketA      -1
2  VendorB  MarketA      -1
4  VendorC  MarketB       1
5  VendorC  MarketX      -1
6  VendorD  MarketA      -1
7  VendorD  MarketX       1
8  VendorE  MarketB       1
9  VendorF  MarketC       1
```

`-1` means the vendor left that market, `1` means he entered it. Depending on what you'd put the focus on you could further sort the result by either of the three columns.

---

**Update**: simple visualization as heatmap (green = vendor entered market; yellow = no change, vendor stayed in market; red = vendor left market; white (background) = no data (vendor not active in this market, neither in period a nor in period b)):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns

df_period_a = pd.DataFrame( {'Vendor': map('Vendor{}'.format, list('AAXZCBBD')),'Market': map('Market{}'.format, list('ABBBXXAA'))})
df_period_b = pd.DataFrame( {'Vendor': map('Vendor{}'.format, list('AXZCBDEF')),'Market': map('Market{}'.format, list('BBBBXXBC'))})

dfa1 = df_period_a.assign(Value=1).set_index(['Vendor','Market'])
dfb1 = df_period_b.assign(Value=1).set_index(['Vendor','Market'])
diff = dfa1.join(dfb1, how='outer', lsuffix='a', rsuffix='b').fillna(0).astype(int)
res = (diff.Valueb - diff.Valuea).rename('Change').reset_index()

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['red','yellow','green'])
ax = sns.heatmap(res.pivot_table('Change', 'Vendor', 'Market'), cmap=cmap)
cb = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cb.set_ticks([-.67, 0, .67])
cb.set_ticklabels(['left', 'stayed', 'entered'])
sns.despine(left=False, bottom=False, top=False, right=False)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: As for visualization, [this survey](https://blog.ouseful.info/2017/11/28/quick-round-up-visualising-flows-using-network-and-sankey-diagrams-in-python-and-r/) might be useful.

Comment: Any advise on which of the visualization options might be useful to visualize the result above?